# Member Functions in C++

Tags: c++

1. To define a member function, we can use the inline function specifier and either the static or virtual (but not both) specifier.
   Why not **both**?
2. A nonstatic member function can have const, volatile, or both function qualifiers.
   How can it have both? If its declared const then how can it be volatile?

Answer (score 9):

**To define a member function, we can use the inline function specifier and either the `static` or `virtual`(but not both) specifier.
Why not both?**

**Answer:**

`virtual` keyword indicates run time evaluation, which means which function to call is evaluated on the basis of `this` at runtime, this is possible because a hidden `this` pointer gets passed to the member functions implicitly, If a function is marked `static` then the `this` pointer is not passed in to the member function. This is because `static` indicates the function is not associated to an instance but it belongs to the class.

From above `virtual`ism cannot work in the absence of `this` and `static` specify's no `this`. Hence `static` and `virtual` cannot be applied at the same time to an function.

**A nonstatic member function can have `const`, `volatile`, or both function qualifiers.
How can it have both? If its declared `const` then how can it be `volatile`?**

**Answer:**

A `const` qualifier indicates that the function will not modify any of the class members. That is the class members are `immutable` inside the function.However, A `const` function can still modify class members which are declared as `mutable` in class definition.

A `volatile` qualifier indicates to the compiler that do not apply(disable) any optimization's For ex: by caching the values in register and not reading them from memory every time.

Given the above, a function can be `const` and yet `volatile`, which tells the compiler that this function does not modify any immutable class members but it can modify `mutable` class members and that compiler should not apply its own optimization(such as register based caching) while dealing with that particular function.

Answer (score 2):

1) `static` functions are not associated with an instance of the class. `virtual` functions are a key concept of polymorphism. I.e. calling a child implementation via a pointer or reference to a base class, so they clearly need an instance of the class to be called (unlike static methods). Virtual calls are possible because of the vftable pointer which is present in the object, so you need an object to make these calls.

2) `const` and `volatile` are completely different. `const` means you can't modify immutable class members, `volatile` means all optimizations are stripped from the processing to prevent skipping checking or modifying `mutable` members. Take into account that you can have `mutable` members, which can be both `volatile` and modified by `const` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of thinking about Question 1:

The `virtual` concept means that the run-time behaviour depends on the concrete *object instance*. Suppose you have a  `Base * p` and you call `p->foo()`. Then the decision which actual function is called depends on the *concrete* object that `p` is actually pointing to.

On the other hand, `static` member functions are *class* functions, meaning they are solely a property of the class (i.e. the *type*), not of an *object*. The virtual concept has no meaning for static member functions, because there's no connection to objects. Static member functions are solely selected based on the *static* type of a variable, if at all:

```
struct Base { static void bar(); virtual ~Base() {} };

Base * p;

p->bar();    // irrelevant what `p` actually points to
Base::bar(); // better syntax, indicates that this has nothing to do with p
```

Summary: static member functions depend only on the *static type*. Virtual member functions depend on the *concrete object*.